# Speeding up A* pathfinding for a massive grid

Tags: python, performance, path-finding, a-star

I am currently trying to fix my pathfinding system in my game. The A pathfinding python code is super slow, considering it has to calculate thousands of nodes each time for my grid. My grid is stored in a dictionary that has the positions of all of the walls and obstacles. Are there any ways I could speed this up **signifigantly**?
Here is my algorithm:

```
def findpath_subgrid(self, start, end):
        self.subgrid_cache.clear()
        start_subgrid = (start[0] // self.subgrid_size, start[1] // self.subgrid_size)
        end_subgrid = (end[0] // self.subgrid_size, end[1] // self.subgrid_size)

        if start_subgrid == end_subgrid:
            return self.find_path(start, end)
        else:
            with self.lock:
                if start_subgrid in self.subgrid_cache:
                    return self.subgrid_cache[start_subgrid]
                else:
                    path = self.find_path(start, end)
                    self.subgrid_cache[start_subgrid] = path
                    return path


    def heuristic(self, a, b):
        return abs(a[0] - b[0]) + abs(a[1] - b[1])

    def find_path(self, start, end):
        queue = []
        heapq.heappush(queue, (0, start))
        came_from = {}
        cost_so_far = {}
        came_from[start] = None
        cost_so_far[start] = 0

        while queue:
            current = heapq.heappop(queue)[1]

            if current == end:
                break

            for next in self.adjacent_cells(current):
                new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + self.cost(current, next)
                if next not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[next]:
                    cost_so_far[next] = new_cost
                    priority = new_cost + self.heuristic(end, next)
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (priority, next))
                    came_from[next] = current

        return self.reconstruct_path(came_from, start, end)

    def adjacent_cells(self, pos):
        x, y = pos
        results = [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)]
        results = filter(self.in_bounds, results)
        results = filter(self.passable, results)
        return results

    def in_bounds(self, pos):
        x, y = pos
        return 0 <= x < 2000 and 0 <= y < 2000

    def passable(self, pos):
        return self.grid.get(pos) != 1  # check if the cell is not an obstacle using the new grid dictionary

    def cost(self, current, next):
        if self.grid.get(next) == 2:
            return 1000  # high cost for cells with enemies
        else:
            return 1  # otherwise, the cost is 1

    def heuristic(self, a, b):
        return abs(a[0] - b[0]) + abs(a[1] - b[1])

    def reconstruct_path(self, came_from, start, goal):
        current = goal
        path = []
        while current != start:
            path.append(current)
            current = came_from[current]
        path.append(start)
        path.reverse()
        return path
```

I've tried subgrids, cache's but its still very very slow.

Comment: Using dictionary is slow, use 2D array.

Comment: Python is really not suited for such intensive task assuming the grid is sufficiently big. A pure-Python code is generally much slower than a native compiled one. You can convert your input to arrays and then use Cython or Numba so to make the code significantly faster (eg. often > x10). For complex data structure, Cython is better than Numba (or even a pure C/C++ code). Keep in mind that Python is designed for scripting, glue code, prototyping, but not for computationally intensive codes (except for vectorized codes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a position is extracted from the queue, you do not need to consider them again in your search (this statement is true because you are working on a grid and using manhattan distance as heuristic function). I added a variable expanded_list to function find_path and adjacent_cells (my Python writing is not the best so you can write them better later). Also it would be better if you use a 2D array for holding your grid instead of a dictionary.

```
def find_path(self, start, end):
        queue = []
        heapq.heappush(queue, (0, start))
        came_from = {}
        cost_so_far = {}
        came_from[start] = None
        cost_so_far[start] = 0
        expanded_list = {}
        expanded_list[current] = False

        while queue:
            current = heapq.heappop(queue)[1]
            expanded_list[current] = True

            if current == end:
                break

            for next in self.adjacent_cells(current):
                expanded_list[next] = False
                new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + self.cost(current, next)
                if next not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[next]:
                    cost_so_far[next] = new_cost
                    priority = new_cost + self.heuristic(end, next)
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (priority, next))
                    came_from[next] = current

        return self.reconstruct_path(came_from, start, end)

    def adjacent_cells(self, pos, expanded_list):
        x, y = pos
        results = [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)]
        results = filter(self.in_bounds, results)
        results = filter(self.passable, results)
        results = filter(lambda pos:not(pos in expanded_list and expanded_list[pos]==True), results)
        return results
```